# How to query this document in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c6b67a937f76029554a96de"
    },
    "1995": [
        {
            "SYMBOL": "20THCENFIN",
            "SERIES": "EQ",
            "OPEN": "75",
            "HIGH": "75",
            "LOW": "75",
            "CLOSE": "75",
            "LAST": "75",
            "PREVCLOSE": "75",
            "TOTTRDQTY": "100",
            "TOTTRDVAL": "7500",
            "TIMESTAMP": "1-AUG-1995",
            "field12": ""
        },
        {
            "SYMBOL": "AARTIIND",
            "SERIES": "EQ",
            "OPEN": "66",
            "HIGH": "66",
            "LOW": "63.05",
            "CLOSE": "63.05",
            "LAST": "63.05",
            "PREVCLOSE": "65.05",
            "TOTTRDQTY": "700",
            "TOTTRDVAL": "45805",
            "TIMESTAMP": "1-AUG-1995",
            "field12": ""
        },
        {
            "SYMBOL": "ABANLLOYD",
            "SERIES": "EQ",
            "OPEN": "150",
            "HIGH": "151",
            "LOW": "149",
            "CLOSE": "150.5",
            "LAST": "150",
            "PREVCLOSE": "150",
            "TOTTRDQTY": "800",
            "TOTTRDVAL": "119800",
            "TIMESTAMP": "1-AUG-1995",
            "field12": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to query Symbol attribute in mongodb? How can I able to to query this doc in mongo shell? 
Other thing if I find correct value which is actually present in my database then it will return true or what?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provided, if you wanted to locate a document that contained a specific `SYMBOL` value (ex: `AARTIIND`, using the Mongo Shell you would query as follows:

```
db.collection.find({ "1995": { $elemMatch: { SYMBOL: "AARTIIND" } } })
```

This will use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator to query an [array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

This would return the entire matching document. Note that this will only work if the schema of each document in the collection contains a `1995` field.

If you only wanted to return the specific matching document within the `1995` array, you could consider writing an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) instead.